# use of the verb NAG in reference to pain, discomfort

Tags: word-meaning, usage, colloquial-language

As a native speaker, I know that persistent pain can be described as **nagging**, as in **nagging back pain**. However, would it be correct/idiomatic for a doctor, for example, to ask a patient **How long has your back *been nagging*?**

Answer (score 1):

How long has your back **been bothering you**?

One can have a nagging pain, but we commonly say:

**How long has X been bothering you? Or causing you discomfort?**

NOT: nagging you because **to nag someone changes the meaning**.

My brother was always nagging me. [picking on me].  Your back cannot pick on you. :)

Merriam Webster:

Definition of nag
nagged; nagging
transitive verb
1 : to irritate by constant scolding or urging [by a person]
2 : badger, worry [by a person]
intransitive verb
1 : to find fault incessantly : complain [nag a person]
2 : t**o be a persistent source of annoyance or distraction**

This problem is nagging me. However, I would not say: my back is nagging me.

Comment: No, it doesn't change the meaning anymore than "heart attack" changes the meaning of *attack*.

Comment: You misunderstood. I would not say: My back is nagging me in an educated register. My mother nags me. My friend nags me. But no thing nags me.

Comment: I'm fine with "my back has been **nagging** me for three days" etc. --
 but as usual, this might just be my American talking.

Comment: @Andrew I am also an AmE native speaker but would not use nag in that manner.

Answer (score 0):

*Nagging* is a perfectly acceptable word to use for describing chronic pain.

> [**nag**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nag) *v.tr.*
>   2. To torment persistently, as with anxiety or pain.

The only difference from what you wrote is that it is more idiomatic to use the verb transitively, as you did with "bothering":

> How long has your back been nagging you?

Comment: Agreed, but not in the way it was originally worded, right?

Comment: It can be used intransitively there, but most people would add the *you* at the end.

Comment: @CocoPop  Your *nagging* pain is one that is nagging *you*.  I've never heard the intransitive form used in this context.

Comment: @Andrew: If you've heard "nagging doubts" then you've heard the verb used intransitively.

Comment: @Robusto; In my answer and in my comment, I wrote nagging as an adjective. nagging is an adjective, not a verb. Nagging doubts are like working titles or any gerund as adjective.

Comment: Gerunds are verbs used as adjectives.